# OSError: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found when using pygel3d in CentOS 7 for Python 3

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, centos, glibc

How can I fix this problem in CentOS7 and for Python 3?

```
from pygel3d import hmesh, gl_display as gl

m = hmesh.load("mesh.obj")
viewer = gl.Viewer()
viewer.display(m)
```

Error is:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a7ca264f9a47> in <module>
----> 1 from pygel3d import hmesh, gl_display as gl
      2 
      3 m = hmesh.load("mesh.obj")
      4 viewer = gl.Viewer()
      5 viewer.display(m)

/scratch3/venv/djrn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pygel3d/__init__.py in <module>
     47 
     48 # Load PyGEL the Python GEL bridge library
---> 49 lib_py_gel = ct.cdll.LoadLibrary(_get_script_path() + "/" + _get_lib_name())
     50 
     51 # An InvalidIndex is just a special integer value.

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py in LoadLibrary(self, name)
    449 
    450     def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 451         return self._dlltype(name)
    452 
    453 cdll = LibraryLoader(CDLL)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    371 
    372         if handle is None:
--> 373             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    374         else:
    375             self._handle = handle

OSError: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /scratch3/venv/djrn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pygel3d/libPyGEL.so)
```

I installed pygel3d using the following command in Jupyter Notebook:

```
!pip install PyGEL3D
```

I get the same error if I am importing open3d:

I installed the `open3d` using this command:

```
! pip install open3d

$ import open3d as o3d
```

Error:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-2bb78b04a701> in <module>
----> 1 import open3d as o3d

/scratch3/venv/djrn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/open3d/__init__.py in <module>
     45     try:  # Preload libc++.so and libc++abi.so (required by filament)
     46         _CDLL(str(next((_Path(__file__).parent).glob('*c++abi.*'))))
---> 47         _CDLL(str(next((_Path(__file__).parent).glob('*c++.*'))))
     48     except StopIteration:  # Not found: check system paths while loading
     49         pass

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    371 
    372         if handle is None:
--> 373             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    374         else:
    375             self._handle = handle

OSError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /scratch3/venv/djrn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/open3d/libc++abi.so.1)
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
Release:    7.9.2009
Codename:   Core
```